# For the cards instead showing in numbers, what way can I changing into something like how human like play it, showing result like 2 of clubs

Tags: python

```
from random import choice as rc

def total(hand):

    aces = hand.count(11)


    t = sum(hand)

    if t > 21 and aces > 0:
        while aces > 0 and t > 21:

            t -= 10
            aces -= 1
    return t

cards = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]

cwin = 0  
pwin = 0 
while True:
    player = []

    player.append(rc(cards))
    player.append(rc(cards))
    pbust = False  
    cbust = False  
    while True:

        tp = total(player)
        print ("The player has these cards %s with a total value of %d" % (player, tp))
        if tp > 21:
            print ("--> The player is busted!")
            pbust = True
            break

        elif tp == 21:
            print ("\a BLACKJACK!!!")
            break

        else:
            hs = input("Hit or Stand/Done (h or s): ").lower()
            if 'h' in hs:
                player.append(rc(cards))
            else:
                break
    while True:

        comp = []
        comp.append(rc(cards))
        comp.append(rc(cards))

        while True:
            tc = total(comp)                
            if tc < 18:
                comp.append(rc(cards))
            else:
                break

        print ("the computer has %s for a total of %d" % (comp, tc))

        if tc > 21:
            print ("--> The computer is busted!")
            cbust = True
            if pbust == False:
                print ("The player wins!")
                pwin += 1
        elif tc > tp:
            print ("The computer wins!")
            cwin += 1
        elif tc == tp:
            print ("It's a draw!")
        elif tp > tc:
            if pbust == False:
                print ("The player wins!")
                pwin += 1
            elif cbust == False:
                print ("The computer wins!")
                cwin += 1
        break

    print ("Wins, player = %d  computer = %d" % (pwin, cwin))
    exit = input("Press Enter (q to quit): ").lower()
    if 'q' in exit:
        break
print ("Thanks for playing blackjack with the computer!")
```

I'm new to python. Just a beginner.
This is not my actual code. I did some tweak into it. But mostly the overall function and the way it executes is almost similar.
Instead of showing just numbers, is there any way to change to 
something like this:
"Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds",
"A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"
but still able to transfer the value represented to be integrated into part of the code. 
I hope can improve my codes as time passes. 
I'm not really familiar with classes yet, although it will make the code looks clean. Hope anyone can point out mistakes or making some improvement.

Comment: Consider: 10 isn't a card; it's the *value* of a card like `("Spades", "J")`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: You seem to want design help; this is out of scope fro Stack Overflow.  Most of all, there are *many* examples of card-playing programs on line; we expect you to do that research before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import choice as rc

def printCardNames(hand):


    for i in hand:
        name = ""
        if(i < 13):
            name += "Spades "
        elif(i < 26):
            name += "Clubs "
        elif(i < 39):
            name += "Hearts "
        else:
            name += "Diamonds "

        cardName = i % 13
        if(cardName == 0):
            name += "2,"
        elif(cardName == 1):
            name += "3,"
        elif(cardName == 2):
            name += "4,"
        elif(cardName == 3):
            name += "5,"
        if(cardName == 4):
            name += "6,"
        if(cardName == 5):
            name += "7,"
        if(cardName == 6):
            name += "8,"
        if(cardName == 7):
            name += "9,"
        if(cardName == 8):
            name += "10,"
        if(cardName == 9):
            name += "J,"
        if(cardName == 10):
            name += "Q,"
        if(cardName == 11):
            name += "K,"
        if(cardName == 12):
            name += "A,"
        print(name)






def total(hand):

    values = []  # I will use value of the cards to calculate total value
    for i in hand:
        values.append(card_values[i])


    aces = values.count(11)


    t = sum(values)

    if t > 21 and aces > 0:
        while aces > 0 and t > 21:

            t -= 10
            aces -= 1
    return t

cards = range(0,52) # I will pick a card, not a card value

card_values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, # corresponding card values
         2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
         2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
         2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]

cwin = 0  
pwin = 0 
while True:
    player = []

    player.append(rc(cards))
    player.append(rc(cards))
    pbust = False  
    cbust = False  
    while True:

        tp = total(player)
        print ("The player has these cards:")
        printCardNames(player)
        print ("Total Value of:", tp)
        if tp > 21:
            print ("--> The player is busted!")
            pbust = True
            break

        elif tp == 21:
            print ("\a BLACKJACK!!!")
            break

        else:
            hs = input("Hit or Stand/Done (h or s): ").lower()
            if 'h' in hs:
                player.append(rc(cards))
            else:
                break
    while True:

        comp = []
        comp.append(rc(cards))
        comp.append(rc(cards))

        while True:
            tc = total(comp)                
            if tc < 18:
                comp.append(rc(cards))
            else:
                break

        print ("the computer has")
        printCardNames(comp)
        print ("Total Value of:", tc)

        if tc > 21:
            print ("--> The computer is busted!")
            cbust = True
            if pbust == False:
                print ("The player wins!")
                pwin += 1
        elif tc > tp:
            print ("The computer wins!")
            cwin += 1
        elif tc == tp:
            print ("It's a draw!")
        elif tp > tc:
            if pbust == False:
                print ("The player wins!")
                pwin += 1
            elif cbust == False:
                print ("The computer wins!")
                cwin += 1
        break

    print ("Wins, player = %d  computer = %d" % (pwin, cwin))
    exit = input("Press Enter (q to quit): ").lower()
    if 'q' in exit:
        break
print ("Thanks for playing blackjack with the computer!")
```

Comment: Wow~ I didn't expect it can be done this way( by adding the string). Thanks for showing the improvement! I will continue to learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with making a deck instead of just numbers:

```
import itertools
suits = ["hearts", "spades", "diamonds", "clubs"]
cards = [("two", 2),
         ("three", 3),
         ("four", 4),
         ("five", 5),
         ("six", 6),
         ("seven", 7),
         ("eight", 8),
         ("nine", 9),
         ("ten", 10),
         ("Jack", 10),
         ("Queen", 10),
         ("King", 10),
         ("Ace", 11)]

deck = list(itertools.product(suits, cards))
```

Then you can index in depending on what you want. When counting you can select the value, when printing you can look at the name and suit.

Some general programming tips:

- Pull more of this out into functions. It would be easier to see your overall program structure if your game loops called well-named functions.
- The number of `while True:` loops in this program is scary. Only use those when you absolutely have to because they are very bug-prone.
- Use whitespace more judiciously. Think of them as paragraph brakes in
  your code.
- Make your variable names more descriptive (`player_total` instead of
  `tp`, `computer_hand` instead of `comp`)